# comparison of Sidekiq::SortedEntry with Sidekiq::SortedEntry failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I've written the snippet below that will identify if a potential job would be unique and if not, it does not run it.  I do this by iterating over each job in the scheduled queue and looking at the job's arguments passed through.  Dependent on the arguments, I can determine if it would be unique:

```
job_exists = { :appointment => false }

Sidekiq::ScheduledSet.new.sort.each do |job|
  case job['args'][0]
  when 'Appointment'
    job_exists[:appointment] = true
  end
end
```

And in the next snippet of code, it simply checks for the boolean value and if it doesn't exist it will run it.

However, I've been getting the error `comparison of Sidekiq::SortedEntry with Sidekiq::SortedEntry` thrown from the line: `Sidekiq::ScheduledSet.new.sort.each do |job|`.

Why is this line causing this error to be thrown?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are sorting the entire set in memory.  Don't do that.

Comment: It happened with only one job in the queue.